# Using async/await on googleapi libraries return undefined

Tags: google-api, async-await, google-api-nodejs-client

Please help, here is the codes:

```
OAuth2Client.setCredentials(tokens)
const oauth2 = google.oauth2({ version: "v2", auth: OAuth2Client })
const userinfo = await oauth2.userinfo.v2.me.get({})
console.log(userinfo)
```

`userinfo` is undefined in `console` log.

I'm using `googleapis@32.0.0` and `nodejs@8.0.0`

this has accidentally happened, it was running well yesterday...

Is it a bug or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved after a night, I woke up and it works...